# docker: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer . The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

Am trying to pull an image from docker hub.

> docker pull zuehlke/shiny

And am facing below error:

`docker: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\d2dab1878cf591d869d33aa2c4cd410cd92614a44c776041c506fc765c1a98f1: The system cannot find the path specified.`

**Am having Docker for Windows:**

docker version

Client:

Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:

Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:50:27 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does `docker pull` work for other images? Is the docker deamon running?

Comment: @Munchkin - Yes. docker daemon is running and am able to pull other images

Comment: Resolved:                                                                                                         I changed my Docker service from Windows to "Switch to Linux Container" and tried to pull the images and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

You have selected Windows Containers at the time of setup rather than Linux Containers so only Windows-based images will run. To resolve this, right-click the tray icon and select 'Switch to Linux Containers' and it will start working.

Answer (score 0):

you must activate the virtualization service.

you must use this command `taskmgr`  and click  performance on windows to verify if it is activated :