# Docker image import error: "Base layer cannot have tombstones"

Tags: linux, windows, docker

I have built a Docker Linux image for Unreal Engine continuous integration builds by following the instructions here: https://docs.adamrehn.com/ue4-docker/use-cases/continuous-integration

Once built (this required an online Linux VM with a ton of disk space), I exported the image, downloaded it onto my Windows 10 machine and attempted to import the image into my local version of Docker for testing.

The import failed and I got the following error:

```
docker image import .\docker-image-linux-ue4-full-opengl.tar
Error response from daemon: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: base layer cannot have tombstones
```

Unless Docker was trying to re-awaken the dead, I have no idea what this is supposed to mean, and neither does Google. Is there any explanation for this error? The only thing I can think of is that the Windows version of Docker is failing to read the image that was produced on Linux, but my understanding was that running a Linux image on Windows should be supported.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: I don't use Windows, but according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769833/docker-failed-to-register-layer-re-exec-error-exit-status-1-output-processb) it looks like you need to manually enable Linux containers when using Docker for Windows?

Comment: After looking at some of the Moby source code, it looks like tombstones are a Docker internal mechanism. You should not have to remove the tombstones manually. It is probably a system misconfiguration, likely that you are running a Linux image on Windows

Comment: The error comes from this file and line in the Moby repo, FYI:

```vendor/github.com/Microsoft/hcsshim/internal/wclayer/baselayer.go
133:    return errors.New("base layer cannot have tombstones")```

Comment: Looks like it was a Linux container support issue, swapping to Linux container mode has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @adamkgray in the comments for pointing me towards the "Enable Linux containers" option, that seems to have fixed the issue. Just a shame the Docker error message wasn't more helpful.